# Android app - Integrate another apk

Tags: android, apk

I am developing an application in android. I have situation wherein I have the need to call another app from the main app. Basically when the user presses a tab in the main app the second app should open and it should remain within the main app tab view.

I have developed the complete code for the main app. I also have the source code for the second app and the apk. I am totally not sure as how to integrate the 2 apps. Based on references I am understanding that we can call the apk of the second app from the first, but I am not clear on the same. Please advice or suggest any steps towards the same.

Regards,
Harry

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367044/integrate-an-android-app-apk-into-an-existing-android-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have situation wherein I have the need to call another app from the main app.

Why? You appear to be the author of both apps. Why not simply combine them?

> Basically when the user presses a tab in the main app the second app should open and it should remain within the main app tab view.

This is not supported, on two levels:

- You cannot embed another application's UI into your own, except via `RemoteViews`
- Embedding activities inside of activities is now deprecated

Answer (score 2):

You can't have one application load inside a tab of another application. You can easily have one application start a second application.

[How to call one android application from another android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728465/how-to-call-one-android-application-from-another-android-application)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it's possible to open up a view from another app in your existing tab view.
It is however possible to start the activity from another app by a button click. This will then allow you to go back with back button to your own app activity.