# How to fix “Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: doc/allclasses-frame.html”

Tags: android, jar, duplicates, javadoc, configure

I compiled two jar files and added them to the build path of my Android project.

I received this error from Eclipse:
Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: doc/allclasses-frame.html

After reading

[How to fix "Error generating final archive: duplicate entry: AndroidManifest.xml"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934185/how-to-fix-error-generating-final-archive-duplicate-entry-androidmanifest-xml)

I realized that I could eliminate the error by re-exporting my jar file without documentation. I did this, and now my project doesn't have any errors, but what about my documentation? Is there a way to see the documentation from my libraries when I use the Ctrl-space autocomplete?

I didn't have to re-export both of the jar files. I only had to re-export the one that is in the same Workspace as the Android project that I'm working on. However, Ctrl-space doesn't show me the documentation from either jar file.

I'd also love to know how to configure a jar file so that links can be generated when I'm generating the javadoc.

Answer (score 6):

You can keep the javadoc in a seperate .jar file, outside of the project folder. Then tell Eclipse where the Javadoc file is located in the project properties > build configuration.

You won't get an error and still get the autocomplete info.