# Android: Jar file with same resource filename as in main app

Tags: android, jar

In my app I have a resource called main.xml. I also have a jar file that contains a resource called main.xml. Up until recently, this was working fine but then I started getting the following error:

Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: res/layout/main.xml

Not sure why all of a sudden. It must be possible to include a resource with the same filename in a jar file. The xml files are in fact located under two completely different paths, so I don't see why this should be a conflict.

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934185/how-to-fix-error-generating-final-archive-duplicate-entry-androidmanifest-xml

Comment: I read that earlier but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to delete the duplicate file as it was not needed. Solved the problem but isn't the correct way to do things.